# Excel, Adding Specific Columns for Multiple Rows

Tags: excel, sum, row, excel-formula

If I have a table something like this:

```
  |A|B|C|D|
1 |1|0|1|
2 |4|4|2|
3 |7|2|3|
4 |5|7|2|
5 |3|9|1|
```

Is it possible to add up column A with column C, and display the result in D "=SUM(A1,C3)"
BUT
I would like to automate this for about 50 rows, so that:

```
D1=SUM(A1,C3), D2=SUM(A2,C2), D3=SUM(A3,C3)...D50=SUM(A50,C50)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by *BUT I would like to automate this* you meann VBA, then try this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim rng As Range
    ' Set rng to the required range, by whatever means needed
    Set rng = [D1:D50]
    ' Set Formulas of the range
    rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-3],RC[-1])"
End Sub
```